# WSO2 - Micro Integrator 4.2.0 - Default user store

Tags: wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-micro-integrator

I am using the micro integrator 4.2.0 for the first time. By default, when calling an API deployed as carbon application with basic authorization, it is trying to connect to LDAP store. However, i dont have any LDAP store, and i just want to use the default admin admin user (same as the previous EI versions). Is this possible? or am i obliged to add an LDAP or RDBMS store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to connect to a userstore for it to work. If you need something different you can implement a custom handler for this.